# HTML text not align

Tags: html, css

My text in HTML its not working, in the middle of 2 lines texts show a white space. I need to fix this in HTML or CSS? and how i fix? Thanks!
OBS: I don't know why Stack Overflow its now showing the red background.

```css
#black {
  background-color: red;
}
#white {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 6%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px;
}
#white h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #40BAD7;
  size: 50px;
}
#white span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#white2 {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
}
#white2 p {
  color: #40BAD7;
  float: left;
}
#white2 span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="black">
  <div id="white">
    <h1><span>ONLINE HÁ MAIS DE 3 ANOS!</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="white2">
    <p><span>Isso mesmo! Começamos em meados de 2013, e agora temos mais de 3 anos de servidor!</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>Venha jogar com os maiores clãs de drift do Brasil, estamos te esperando!</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean to ask why your `<p>` element has a 16px margin on both the top and bottom?

Comment: Where it has 16px? I really didn't understand.
https://i.gyazo.com/12488ed10f1806d3390478cbc7fdadd8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the content *overlaps* the `<div id="black">`. That's why you don't see the red color.

If you want to put the paragraphs together give them `margin: 0`.

```css
#black {
  background-color: red;
}
#white {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 6%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px;
}
#white h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #40BAD7;
  size: 50px;
}
#white span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#white2 {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
}
#white2 p {
  color: #40BAD7;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#white2 span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="black">
  red
  <div id="white">
    <h1><span>ONLINE HÁ MAIS DE 3 ANOS!</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="white2">
    <p><span>Isso mesmo! Começamos em meados de 2013, e agora temos mais de 3 anos de servidor!</span>
    </p>
    <p><span>Venha jogar com os maiores clãs de drift do Brasil, estamos te esperando!</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```